# Dynamically generate public static

Tags: arrays, static, computer-science, public, dynamically-generated

I pass a string from VVVV to Unity via UDP, which is made up of multiple float groups, each one defined by a Char at the beginning, and an "!" at the end.

`K0.0322 2.1062 4.2102 49.9711 43.2255!V44.7385 47.2003 49.8143 49.4658 4.1806 12.6100 6.2053!C49.9437 16.4352`

I want to dynamically generate arrays with the content of each group

```
float[] k = {0.0322, 2.1062.........};
float[] v = {44.7385, 47.2003........};
```

and make them accessible for other unity scripts as public static.
Is this possible?

These public statics have to be initialized at the beginning of the script, so if they are generated dynamically they won't exist at the start.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you can try using **list**

```
Public static List<float> newlist= new  List<float>❨❩;
```